# How to map unknown varying fields using Jackson

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1519296206,
    "base": "USD",
    "date": "2021-03-17",
    "rates": {
        "GBP": 0.72007,
        "JPY": 107.346001,
        "EUR": 0.813399,
    }
}
```

How can I serialize it to a java object? I've created the object:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CurrencyExchangeRateResponse {
    private Boolean success;
    private Boolean historical;
    private String date;
    private long timestamp;
    private String base;
    private List<Rate> rates;
}


public enum Currency {
    AUD,
    GBP,
    HKD,
    // Other currency codes
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class Rate {
    private Currency currency;
    private Double value;
}
```

However I get the following error during deserialization:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.ceg.platform.currency.impl.Rate>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

As can be seen from the error above the part that causes the error is:

```
"rates": {
    "GBP": 0.72007,
    "JPY": 107.346001,
    "EUR": 0.813399,
}
```

Comment: try a map of <String, Double> or <Currency,Double>

Comment: @experimentunit1998X
Changing 
private Rates rates;
to
private Map<Currency,Double> rates;

did the trick. Thanks! You can post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has below structure

```
"rates": {
    "GBP": 0.72007,
    "JPY": 107.346001,
    "EUR": 0.813399,
}
```

This is an object, notice **{** and **}**. For any array (List in Java), it should be **[** and **]**.

You should change below

```
private List<Rate> rates;
```

to

```
private Map<Currency, Double> rates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is simple, json rates is object, not an array, u have wrong model in code

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp